# Can CentOS 7 run without Python 2.7

Tags: centos, python, yum, python3

Now that Python 2.7 has officially reached end of life, with no new security patches expected, there is a push at my company to delete Python 2.7 from all machines. Running CentOS 7, yum (at least) still requires Python 2.7, and will fail under Python 3. Are there any plans to update Yum and any other packages that depend on Python 2.7, or any work-arounds that can be used to eliminate Python 2.7 and still keep a functining, secure Linux environment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CentOS 7 requires Python 2.7 and it will continue to be supported with security patches from RedHat, [RedHat will be supporting Python2 through part of the lifecycle of RedHat/CentOS 8](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4455511) until CentOS 7 goes End of Life in 2024.

CentOS 7 does support installing newer versions of Python alongside the default version (look into the CentOS Software Collections, `yum install centos-release-scl`), but you cannot replace or remove Python 2.7 from your system without breaking things.

You could use CentOS 8, which defaults to Python 3.6, but also has Python 2.7 available for the time being.

Comment: CentOS 8 also has that interesting bit about not having a python command at all, preferring python2 or python3 so the app/user is specific.

Comment: For security reasons, we really did want to delete Python 2, but your answer matches everything else I've seen.